# confusion with add_filter

Tags: filters

I am trying to customize the default WordPress search field. So I thought I could add a filter to remove the function and then add in a new function with the fields the way I want them. So I tried this

```
 function savior_search(){
     <form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="<?php echo home_url( '/');        ?>">
    <input type="text" value="" name="s" id="s" />
</form>
<?php }

 add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'savior_search');
```

It seems to work but for some reason that I don't understand, it duplicates the search field. It puts the form on the page twice. I also commented out get_search_form in the sidebar yet when I refresh my page, it's still there. I am using the filter incorrectly? My search function is in the functions.php.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your syntax is wrong, you're mixing up the `html` and `php function` at the beginning.

See Filter here - [wp-includes/general-template.php#L151](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/3.4.1/wp-includes/general-template.php#L151)

I think we should return the form, instead of printing it, See my example, It should work, If you want to modify something, do it in function.

**Example -**

```
function savior_search(){

    //Modify This
    $form = '<form role="search" method="get" id="searchform" action="' . esc_url( home_url( '/' ) ) . '" >
                <div><label class="screen-reader-text" for="s">' . __('Search for:') . '</label>
                    <input type="text" value="' . get_search_query() . '" name="s" id="s" />
                    <input type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="'. esc_attr__('Search') .'" />
                </div>
            </form>'; 

    return $form;
}

add_filter( 'get_search_form', 'savior_search');
```